# issues trying to add elements in an activity which extends fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-listfragment

I am building a basic application which displays data from a database in a list View. Which worked properly, I decided to add a **sliding menu using navigation drawer** Which uses Activities that extends to fragment So I've been changing all my classes to extends fragment So they can be added to the new navigation menu.
My problem is : in one of my classes **AllBarsActivity** I added  list which displays data from the database, in order to do that the **AllBarsActivity** extends **ListActivity**. 
My navigation system uses classes that extends to  **fragment** I did that so now I am getting errors. my question is how do u add a listview in a fragment.
Here is my previous before trying to add the slide menu  navigation drawer:

```
    public class AllBarsActivity extends ListActivity {



        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     // might have to change json import///////////
        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> barsList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_bars = "http://www.milamboltd.freeserver.me/android_login_api/get_all_bars.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_BARS = "bars";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_ARTIST = "artist";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_CREATED_AT= "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_UPLOADEDBY = "uploadedBy";


    String userLoggedIn;
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";






    // bars JSONArray
    JSONArray bars = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_bars);

     // getting bar details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting bar id (pid) from intent
        userLoggedIn = i.getStringExtra(KEY_EMAIL);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        barsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading bars in Background Thread
        new LoadAllBars().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single bar
        // launching Edit bar Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



               @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                            .toString();

    //                // Starting new intent
    //                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
    //                        EditBarActivity.class);
    //                // sending pid to next activity
    //                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
    // 
                    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                  //  startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
            });

        }


    // Response from Edit Bar Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted bar
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all bar by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllBars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllBarsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading bars. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All bars from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_bars, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
           Log.d("All Bars: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // bars found
                    // Getting Array of bars
                    bars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BARS);

                    // looping through All bars
                    for (int i = 0; i < bars.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = bars.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String artist = c.getString(TAG_ARTIST);
                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String uploadedBy = c.getString(TAG_UPLOADEDBY);
                        String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                        String created_at = c.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_ARTIST, artist);
                        map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                        map.put(TAG_UPLOADEDBY, uploadedBy);
                        map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                        map.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);





                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        barsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no bars found
                    // Launch Add New bar Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewBarActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all bars
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                              AllBarsActivity.this, barsList,
                              R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                      TAG_TITLE,TAG_ARTIST,TAG_DESCRIPTION,TAG_UPLOADEDBY},


>                     new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.title,R.id.artist, R.id.description,R.id.created_at });
>                       // updating listview
>                       setListAdapter(adapter);
>                   }
>               });
>    
>           }
>    
>       }   }
```

**and here is the fragment class I am trying convert it to :**

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {


     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 // might have to change json import///////////
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> barsList;
// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_bars = "http://www.milamboltd.freeserver.me/android_login_api/get_all_bars.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_BARS = "bars";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_ARTIST = "artist";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_CREATED_AT= "created_at";
private static final String TAG_UPLOADEDBY = "uploadedBy";

String userLoggedIn;
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

// bars JSONArray
JSONArray bars = null;

public WhatsHotFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,


           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);

        // getting bar details from intent
        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();

        // getting bar id (pid) from intent
        userLoggedIn = i.getStringExtra(KEY_EMAIL);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        barsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading bars in Background Thread
        new LoadAllBars().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single bar
        // launching Edit bar Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

//                // Starting new intent
//                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
//                        EditBarActivity.class);
//                // sending pid to next activity
//                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
// 
                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
              //  startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all bar by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllBars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading bars. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All bars from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_bars, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
           Log.d("All Bars: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // bars found
                    // Getting Array of bars
                    bars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BARS);



// looping through All bars
                for (int i = 0; i < bars.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = bars.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String artist = c.getString(TAG_ARTIST);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String uploadedBy = c.getString(TAG_UPLOADEDBY);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String created_at = c.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_ARTIST, artist);
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_UPLOADEDBY, uploadedBy);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);





                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    barsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no bars found
                // Launch Add New bar Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        NewBarFragment.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all bars
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                          AllBarsActivity.this, barsList,
                          R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                  TAG_TITLE,TAG_ARTIST,TAG_DESCRIPTION,TAG_UPLOADEDBY},
                          new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.title,R.id.artist, R.id.description,R.id.created_at });
                  // updating listview
                  setListAdapter(adapter);
              }
          });

      }

  }
}
```

I get errors on these lines of codes:
1. it says **he method getListView() is undefined for the type 
 WhatsHotFragment**

```
 // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();
```

1. It says the method **runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){})** is undefined for the 
    type WhatsHotFragment.LoadAllBars.

-and No enclosing instance of the type AllBarsActivity is accessible in scope

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all bars
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */                   
                      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                              AllBarsActivity.this, barsList,
                              R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                      TAG_TITLE,TAG_ARTIST,TAG_DESCRIPTION,TAG_UPLOADEDBY},
                              new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.title,R.id.artist, R.id.description,R.id.created_at });
                      // updating listview
                      setListAdapter(adapter);
                  }
              });

   edit:
```

I added  a public void oncreated to add the listview but and its says content view not yet created.

```
'public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){


    ListView lv = getListView();

}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ListFragment instead of Fragment and you can use the list features as in ListActivity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

If you are using runOnUiThread inside a fragment call getActivity() first.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable())
```

Comment: Thank the Listfragment work and the getactivity is fixed but  my list adapter is still giving me an error saying my list adapter is undefined.

Comment: When instantiating your adapter make sure you change AllBarsActivity.this to getActivity() also.

Comment: the is gone but says content not created on this line '        ListView lv = getListView();
'

Comment: Make sure you are not calling getListView() inside your onCreateView. With fragments the content is not created until after that method. Try putting that code in OnActivityCreated() instead.

Comment: I added a 'public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ListView lv = getListView();
       
 }' just under the oncreateView and now it says did not call through to super.OnActivitycreated

Comment: I fixed I just added Add super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 in the onActivitycreated , thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure you are calling   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
and not super.onCreate(). super.onCreate() should only be called from the onCreate() method.